# Vuetify checkboxes array checks all boxes when list changes

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuetify.js

I'm pretty new to both vue and vuetify so there might be a few horrible lines in my code, but I'm really struggling with this one and a bit of help would be nice.

I have an array of checkboxes generated with a v-for loop on an "items" array. This array of checkboxes is attached to a model array just like [this example](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101) from the vuetify documentation.

It looks like the code below.

The problem is : if I change the items array, even when the model array is still empty, all checkboxes end up checked.

Here is my template :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <div>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item 
               v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"
             >
              <v-checkbox 
                 v-model="model" :label="item.name"  
                          :value="item" 
                          :value-comparator="comparator"
                          ></v-checkbox>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
          <v-btn @click="updateItems">Change elements</v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and the script

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      model: [],
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Item1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Item2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Item3"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Item4"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
   methods: {
    comparator(a, b) {
      return a.id == b.id;
    },
       updateItems() {
            this.items = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Element1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Element2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Element3"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Element4"
        }
      ]
    }
   }
});
```

And a [codepen is way easier to understand](https://codepen.io/Schnaffon/pen/xxxgvNW?editors=1111)

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, if you have any idea, that would be welcome. Thank you !

EDIT : I had made a mistake in my code. Fixed it. The question is still the same though.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to achieve this? I don't understand what is the use of the model arr when you update all the items in the first place? Ifyou could explain your situation, maybe there is a simpler way to go about it.

Comment: I'm using the model array somewhere else. I want to know what items are selected but need to add items to the list of selectable items from time to time

Comment: In that I recommend you make a new array called `totalSelected` and when you click the button, save the model arr into totalSelected and then safely reset both data and model. I don't think there is a cleaner way.

Comment: That's actually the cleanest way to do it indeed.
I added `this.model = this.model.slice(0)` and the problem is gone. I'm still not quite sure why it happened, but at least it works now. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

There are few bugs in this code,

from the below checkbox

```
<v-checkbox 
  v-model="model" :label="item.name"  
  :value="item" 
  :value-comparator="comparator"
></v-checkbox>
```

> :value-comparator is triggers when you click on checkbox, it tries to
>   match with all other value and returns true only for the selected id

"comparator" function is not available in your methods, **replace "valueCompare"** method with **"comparator"**

when you click on change elements, it resets items array but you are **not reseting the model**

> working codepen : https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/rNNyBgQ
>
> Added fixs and final code looks like this

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <div>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item 
                         v-for="item in items"                            :key="item.id"
             >
           <v-checkbox v-model="model"              :label="item.name"  
             :value="item" 
        :value-comparator="comparator"
           ></v-checkbox>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
          <v-btn @click="updateItems">Change elements</v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

// Looking for the v1.5 template?
// https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/GVoaNe

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      model: [],
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Item1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Item2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Item3"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Item4"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
   methods: {
    comparator(a, b) {
      console.log(a, b);
      return a.id == b.id;
    },
       updateItems() {
         this.model = [];
            this.items = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Element1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Element2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Element3"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Element4"
        }
      ]
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: As for the comparator, thank you, I fixed it. But I don't understand why I should reset model, as it should still be empty since I didn't check anything.

Comment: Yes, checkbox is dependent on items array, when you reset with new values. Already v-model is having some selected values that comes from items array, due to vue reactivity behaviour, I tried to trigger comparator when items value changes. Put console.log(a,b) inside comparator, you will get to know the behaviour. Do upvote and accept this answer as well ..